# Need to update database without losing data in Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using **EntityFramework CodeFirst**, I have added a relation to one of the tables but when I am trying to update the database from package manager console, I need to add -verbose flag but I have data on my table and need to keep them. Is there a way to change the database without losing data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually edit the Up and Down methods of the migration to add relation on the database by adding t-sql commands.